# After installing the SDK, how do I use Core Plot in an application?

Tags: iphone, core-plot

I have set up the Core Plot SDK using the new installer.  I followed the instructions [here](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/wiki/UsingCorePlotInApplications), but I'm not sure how to proceed next.

After installing the SDK, how do I use Core Plot within my application?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples provided with Core Plot. Those should give you some ideas where to start. If you have specific questions, ask them here or on the [Core Plot discussion board](http://groups.google.com/group/coreplot-discuss/topics).